# I can't scale / resize a mesh from python

Tags: python

I have the following code that I obtained from github. I really am very novice and for experimentation purposes I wanted to add some things, but nothing seems to work. I have seen some videos about python and blender; but after many attempts to use those methods or functions, I decided to come here and ask for help:

I would like to modify the Addon: "View3D > Add > Mesh > Add Spring"

Blender Version: 2.93

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import *
from math import sin, cos, pi, atan2
from mathutils import Vector, Euler  

def make_coil(self):

# variables and shortnames
amp = self.profile_radius
n_verts = self.num_verts
n_turns = self.num_turns
th = self.height / n_turns
ipt = self.iterations_per_turn
radius = self.coil_radius
diameter = radius * 2
two_pi = 2.0 * pi
section_angle = two_pi / n_verts
rad_slice = two_pi / ipt
total_segments = (ipt * n_turns) + 1
z_jump = self.height / total_segments

x_rotation = atan2(th / 2, diameter)

n = n_verts        
Verts = []
for segment in range(total_segments):
    rad_angle = rad_slice * segment    

    for i in range(n):
        
        # create the vector
        this_angle = section_angle * i
        x_float = amp * sin(this_angle) + radius
        z_float = amp * cos(this_angle)
        v1 = Vector((x_float, 0.0, z_float))
        
        # rotate it
        xz_euler = Euler((-x_rotation, 0.0, -rad_angle), 'XYZ')
        v1.rotate(xz_euler)
        
        # add extra z height per segment
        v1 += Vector((0, 0, (segment * z_jump)))
        
        # append it
        Verts.append(v1)

Faces = []
# skin it, normals facing outwards
for t in range(total_segments-1):
    for i in range(n-1):
        p0 = i + (n*t) 
        p1 = i + (n*t) + 1
        p2 = i + (n*t + n) + 1 
        p3 = i + (n*t + n)
        Faces.append([p3,p2,p1,p0])
    p0 = n*t
    p1 = n*t + n
    p2 = n*t + (2 * n) - 1
    p3 = n*t + n-1
    Faces.append([p3,p2,p1,p0])

return Verts, Faces


def create_mesh_object(context, verts, edges, faces, name):

mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(name)
mesh.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces)
mesh.update()

from bpy_extras import object_utils
return object_utils.object_data_add(context, mesh, operator=None)



class AddSpringObject(bpy.types.Operator):

bl_idname = "mesh.spring_add"
bl_label = "Add Spring"
bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO', 'PRESET'}

num_verts : IntProperty(name="num profile verts",
    description="how many verts in profile shape",
    default=12, min=1, max=30)

profile_radius : FloatProperty(name="profile radius",
    description="Radius of profile shape",
    default=0.01, min=0.01, max=20.0)

coil_radius : FloatProperty(name="coil radius",
    description="Coil radius measured from center of profile shape",
    default=0.04, min=0.01, max=20.0)

iterations_per_turn : IntProperty(name="num segments per turn",
    description="how many profile segments per turn",
    default=11, min=1, max=30)

num_turns : IntProperty(name="total turns in coil",
    description="how many turns in coil",
    default=8, min=1, max=30)

height : FloatProperty(name="coil height",
    description="Coil height measured from first to last profile 
centers.",
    default=0.40, min=0.01, max=20.0)

def execute(self, context):

    verts, faces = make_coil(self)
    base = create_mesh_object(context, verts, [], faces, "Spring")

    return {'FINISHED'}


def add_object_button(self, context):
self.layout.operator(
    AddSpringObject.bl_idname,
    text="Spring",
    icon='PLUGIN')

def register():
bpy.utils.register_class(AddSpringObject)
bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_mesh_add.append(add_object_button)


def unregister():
bpy.utils.unregister_class(AddSpringObject)
bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_mesh_add.remove(add_object_button)


if __name__ == "__main__":
register()
```

Basically what it does is the following:

[image: image showing a spring being added using the add-on]

However, I would like to know what I can do to add some option so that the object is scaled in a uniform way. I would appreciate any help.
I have tried to add in the menu the option to scale XYZ but it doesn't seem to work.

not working:
[image: the same, showing adding properties for X, Y, and Z scaling]

******EDIT******
ok guys, I was finally able to solve the problem, with something that now seems so silly and simple hahaha.

I'll try to explain it by taking parts of the code, so just add to the "make_coil" function

```
# scale
# new line add
v1 *= scl
```

new class

```
def make_coil(self):

# variables and shortnames
amp = self.profile_radius
n_verts = self.num_verts
n_turns = self.num_turns
th = self.height / n_turns
ipt = self.iterations_per_turn
radius = self.coil_radius
scl = self.scale

diameter = radius * 2
two_pi = 2.0 * pi
section_angle = two_pi / n_verts
rad_slice = two_pi / ipt
total_segments = (ipt * n_turns) + 1
z_jump = self.height / total_segments

x_rotation = atan2(th / 2, diameter)

n = n_verts        
Verts = []
for segment in range(total_segments):
    rad_angle = rad_slice * segment    

    for i in range(n):
        
        # create the vector
        this_angle = section_angle * i
        x_float = amp * sin(this_angle) + radius
        z_float = amp * cos(this_angle)
        v1 = Vector((x_float, 0.0, z_float))
        
        # rotate it
        xz_euler = Euler((-x_rotation, 0.0, -rad_angle), 'XYZ')
        v1.rotate(xz_euler)
        
        # add extra z height per segment
        v1 += Vector((0, 0, (segment * z_jump)))
        
        # scale
        # new line add
        v1 *= scl
        
        # append it
        Verts.append(v1)

Faces = []
# skin it, normals facing outwards
for t in range(total_segments-1):
    for i in range(n-1):
        p0 = i + (n*t) 
        p1 = i + (n*t) + 1
        p2 = i + (n*t + n) + 1 
        p3 = i + (n*t + n)
        Faces.append([p3,p2,p1,p0])
    p0 = n*t
    p1 = n*t + n
    p2 = n*t + (2 * n) - 1
    p3 = n*t + n-1
    Faces.append([p3,p2,p1,p0])

return Verts, Faces
```

so just add this line of code to the "AddSpring" class

```
    scale : FloatProperty(name="coil scale",
    description="how many scale in coil",
    default=1.00, min=0.01, max=30.00)
```

nueva funcion:

```
class AddSpringObject(bpy.types.Operator):

bl_idname = "mesh.spring_add"
bl_label = "Add Spring"
bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO', 'PRESET'}

num_verts : IntProperty(name="num profile verts",
    description="how many verts in profile shape",
    default=12, min=3, max=30)

profile_radius : FloatProperty(name="profile radius",
    description="Radius of profile shape",
    default=1.00, min=0.01, max=20.00)

coil_radius : FloatProperty(name="coil radius",
    description="Coil radius measured from center of profile shape",
    default=4.00, min=0.01, max=20.00)

iterations_per_turn : IntProperty(name="num segments per turn",
    description="how many profile segments per turn",
    default=20, min=4, max=30)

num_turns : IntProperty(name="total turns in coil",
    description="how many turns in coil",
    default=4, min=1, max=30)

height : FloatProperty(name="coil height",
    description="Coil height measured from first to last profile 
centers.",
    default=8.00, min=2.00, max=20.00)

##new code line
scale : FloatProperty(name="coil scale",
    description="how many scale in coil",
    default=1.00, min=0.01, max=30.00)

def execute(self, context):

    verts, faces = make_coil(self)
    base = create_mesh_object(context, verts, [], faces, "Spring")

    return {'FINISHED'}
```

[Source Code from github that works in 2.7 or 2.8 blender](https://gist.github.com/zeffii/5488993)

Comment: You need to modify either the routine `make_coil` that actually calculates the coil or the routine `create_mesh_object` or even the `execute` routine to use the preset scale information you added.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I really do not understand that I have to modify it to make it really work, I would appreciate your help, even more please Thanks

Comment: try to use the script addon_add_object in blender template menu.
with a scale property and inheriting AddObjectHelper in the operator, it should work

Comment: thanks @UneconscienceUneSource, If it's not too much to ask, how can I do what you tell me "inheriting AddObjectHelper in the operator"

Comment: I meant like in the template.
class OBJECT_OT_add_object(Operator, AddObjectHelper):
the class is inheriting AddObjectHelper there. which helps for the object creation...

Comment: i solved it guys, thanks to all, and i edit the post. only add this line code: "v1 *= scl" on "make_coil" function, and add "FloatProperty" in "AddSpringObject" class

Comment: @blackcall2 please write an answer in the answer section below rather than adding solved to the title. This is not a forum that keeps all information in the question. Posts are divided between question and answer. Please read the [tour] for more on how the site works.

Comment: I'm very sorry, thank you @Timaroberts